# If there is no speed limit on space-time compression, why do gravitational waves travel at light-speed?

Tags: faster-than-light, gravitational-waves, warp-drives

From what I've read about spacetime and general relativity it seems there is no limit on how quickly space-time can be compressed or expanded. Why then gravitational waves are limited to light speed?

*[Edit: I removed references to the Alcubierre metric since they are not relevant to the question]*

Comment: The Alcubierre metric assumes the existence of exotic matter with negative energy density. Now, that's cheating... imagine I could make a thermal bath with negative thermodynamic temperature... BINGO! Instant perpetual motion machine! Trillions in my pocket after my free energy power plants are up and running! I am going to be the king of the world! Well, I will be as soon as I discover that negative temperature bath... and Alcubierre will take you to the stars with his warp drive... as soon as he finds exotic matter. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm aware that Alcubierre is _cheating_, but isn't he right about the absence of limitations on the speed of spacetime compression? Why then gravitational waves are limited to _c_?

Comment: I am cheating with my free energy power plants, am I not? But am I not also right by simply ignoring the third law of thermodynamics? Who needs that, anyway? That's basically your question.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Alcubierre did not propose any physical method to create the warp bubble; what he did was to find a solution consistent with the Einstein field equations, essentially starting with the desired results.  This is called being clever.  It's up to us to find a way to implement it; so far no luck.

Comment: I am sure you noticed that I am not proposing any physical method to create a negative temperature bath, either. Let me know when you come across one, since I want to collect my trillion bucks. :-) Are you, by the way, aware of the term "garbage in, garbage out"? That's pretty much what Alcubierre was doing.

Comment: If you don't like warp-drives, then what fast compressions or expansions are you thinking of? Wormholes? That requires exotic matter too? Or are you just talking about nonlocal separations, like two galaxies having the comoving distance grow at faster than lightspeed. Sure you can have the comoving distance between a gravitational source and receiver grow at faster than lightspeed. You can also do that with a source and receiver of rocks. Because there is no limit (other than the possibly finite size of the universe) to how fast the comoving distance between two points cab grow.

Comment: @Timaeus I'm not thinking of the way the compression is generated, I'm asking why perturbation of spacetime travel at _c_ when the medium in which they travel has no limit on how fast it can be compressed/expanded. (maybe it's just the way it is and we don't know why or maybe I've made some bad assumption)

Comment: @drakyoko I totally told you exactly how to get a wave from here to there at a *faster-than-light* speed. And yet you want to ask me why that isn't possible? That would be like asking how you can get light to travel at less than speed $c$ and then when you are told you can do it passing it through water or glass you edit out the part of your question that mentioned water and glass. Just right down a solution for a wave travelling at *faster-than-light* and compute the Einstein tensor, divide it by a constant to get the total Stress-Energy tensor and then note it has exotic matter.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, gravitational waves travel at speed $c$ locally, so to someone inside a warp bubble, a gravitational wave also inside the bubble still keeps pace with light that is also inside the bubble.

Secondly, gravitational waves (like electromagnetic waves) only travel at speed $c$ in a vacuum. And you can't make a warp bubble out of vacuum spacetime. You need exotic matter in places, which makes it not a vacuum in those places.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not interested in a gravitational wave _inside_ a warp bubble. I mentioned the Alcubierre metric just as evidence (flawed maybe? but why?) that spacetime can be compressed faster than _c_ and since, as far as I know, gravitational waves are just waves of compressions of spacetime I see no reasons for them to be limited to _c_

Comment: @drakyoko A gravitational wave inside a warp bubble is exactly **how** to get a gravitational wave from here to there faster than light. Other options include traversable wormholes (which **also** require exotic matter, just like warp drives). So I literally answered your question. I don't know why you have even the slightest objection, so I don't know how to improve the answer. If you want to send a gravitational wave faster then you know what you need: exotic matter.

Answer (score 0):

*There is no such thing as a limiting speed c for gravitational waves!*

With this question, you have hit on an important topic that is usually badly discussed in lectures, articles and books.
*There is no general law that says that the velocity of gravitational waves and gravitational perturbations is necessarily c. Nor is there any law that says that they cannot exceed the limit c.* Yet they are almost always quoted as if they were proven theorems!

The misinterpretation originates from the fact that Einstein derived the speed c for a special type of gravitational waves - by the so-called linearized Einstein equations. *So it is a special approximation when the spacetime over which the waves propagate can be taken as Minkowski spacetime and the intensity of the waves is weak. Clearly this is an important but very special type of all gravitational waves and effects.*

It has been 100 years since then, and no one has been able to produce a similar derivation for all gravitational wave and effect propagation cases. But many researcher have tried many times... For some other special spacetimes there are similar approximate results.
**But the question of the velocity of propagation of weak and strong gravitational waves and perturbations of curved spacetimes remains open, despite the false myth.**

In fact, in advanced research that attempts to describe gravitational effects propagating in curved spacetimes ( coupled to material fields), *it is usually concluded that the waves propagate at a speed other than c!* They do not have a uniform velocity, but have a wide range of velocities depending on the couplings, the parameters and the way the approximation is made. They can propagate at speeds less than c, but also at speeds greater than c. This is all the best theoretical models can tell us for now. See for example this source, I highlight one statement in the abstract:
"We show that for the choice of interaction signs implied by S-matrix and spectral density positivity bounds suggested by analyticity and causality, *the speed of gravitational waves is in general superluminal at
low-energies on NEC preserving backgrounds,* meaning gravitational waves travel faster than allowedby the metric to which photons and Standard Model fields are minimally coupled. "- [The Speed of Gravity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.00881.pdf)

Comment: the speed of a wave is the speed of local "updating" of its locality. A wave can only travel as fast as the updating time quanta, and the observed c reflects this updating speed. It's not clear if one can "fold" space geometry such that far away regions are updated as local neighbors. Have this been shown to be possible?